# Can you create a complete website with only one page?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Can you create a complete website with only one page?

So using XHTML, CSS, and JavaScript. You can change the content and structure of a web page.  Could you build a website (that would normally have multiple pages), but instead bundle it all into one page essentially, and use JavaScript to change the structure and content of the web page so drastically that it essentially is a new page of information?

Could you let the browser open an initial set of information the browser would show, and then use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to load the rest of the information to display the rest of the web pages. Is this practical?

Comment: In short, yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Comment: It's done quite often in fact

Comment: http://rlemon.github.com/FragBuilder.js/ designed to pass in entire templates or blocks of content as JSON *like* data. might be helpful.

Comment: if you do go this route, I recommend looking into a deep-linking page structure using hashtags so that users can easily bookmark a specific page-state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Definitely](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definately), yes. Just try it out!

Comment: Since this was the first answer I will just check it, once it lets me.

Comment: @Matt you should reconsider, does not provide insight or a means by which you can do it.

Comment: @GlennDayton He asked if it is possible. It is, and he did NOT ask any other info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. One way to do it is with something like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org). It wants to communicate with a server-side RESTful API by default, but it can also use html5 storage, which is what its [example todo app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html) does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Ajax.

In fact, this is an application type ([Singe Page App](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application)) specifically supported by Microsoft's ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: **downvoter**: From the FAQ: *Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but why would you want to? It would kill any attempt at good SEO.

Comment: SEO isn't a primary goal of every website.

Comment: True, but between SEO issues and accessibility issues, there would have to be an exceedingly good reason to do it for me to be comfortable with the idea.

Comment: What makes a single page app less accessible?

Comment: He's not looking to make an app. He's looking to make a web site. As far as accessibility, not all mobile devices support javascript. Additionally, most screen readers (e.g. for visually impaired folks) don't support it either.

Comment: 98.4% of screen readers seems like pretty good support,http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/javascript-and-screenreaders/ ... and  and I can't think of any mobile devices that have both a web browser and no javascript, what device would this be? Avoiding javascript for accessibility reasons is mantra from a bygone era. You will lose far more users because your web site parties like it's 1999, e.g. slow, ugly, and clunky, than you will from people who can't use javascript.

Comment: "accessibility" is more than a number on a chart.  pure-JS sites are more brittle (if your JS doesn't load, doesn't work with my browser, etc...), are impossible to access with the myriad of tools that speak HTTP but aren't GUI browsers, often interfere with native browser controls like history and bookmarking, and so on.  github does this right: JS speeds it up, but everything works _exactly the same_ for a client with no JS support whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Entirely possible BUT bad idea for accessibility reasons. If someone has turned off Javascript they will not be able to view the multiple pages to the single page website. I would recommend that you build the site using PHP. You can implement the same "one-page" idea, but using the [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function with `.inc` files. To get the multiple page effect all you have to do is change variables in the URL. For example:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php             <- index
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=faq    <- FAQs
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=login  <- login
...
```

Just changing the `$_REQUEST` variable `page` with a new string would allow you to render multiple pages. The PHP code that would allow you to do this would look something like this:

```
<?php
...
$page = $_REQUEST['page'];
if(isset($page)){
    if(file_exists($page.".inc"))
        include($page.".inc");
    else
        echo "Page does not exist. Try Again.";
else
    include('main.inc');
...
?>
```

Contained within the various `.inc` files would be your HTML code corresponding to the various pages of the website.

Comment: it's not 1997 any more; we have rather better ways of building websites than query arguments and `.inc` files.  find a framework to your liking.  perhaps [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: @Eevee Pretty inconsiderate of you to downvote my detailed and CORRECT answer with a link to a framework that takes time/effort to embed into a website. It's important that Matt gets a quick view into how it can be done on a basic level. Also, I just looked at Flask and it's a python framework, not a PHP framework.

Comment: your answer works, but it certainly has nothing to do with the question, and it's not code i condone anyone writing; poorly reinventing routing from scratch is a terrible way to get started in web development.  Flask will do that for you, as well as save you from XSS and SQL injection and various other "basic level" PHP pitfalls, so you can focus on actually building your website.  i'm sure similar PHP products exist, but i'm not familiar enough with any to recommend one.